# Combinations for tiling two textures together

Tags: 2d, textures, tiles

Hi I need to create seamless ground with grass and dirt. I can make two textures connect seamlessly one to another. My question is how to figure out all the combinations, like (left, top, bottom, left-bottom, right-botton-left and so on)? Is there some kind of guide? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are also hexagon tiles that can make some things easier. A great explanation how to use tiling hexagonal textures is on Curious Expedition game wiki: https://curious-expedition.fandom.com/wiki/Modding:Tiles#Tile_Sprites

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There's a [solid overview of different popular tile combination patterns put together by Boris the Brave](https://www.boristhebrave.com/2013/07/14/tileset-roundup/), building on [some earlier work by Sean Howard](http://www.squidi.net/three/entry.php?id=166).

I'll briefly summarize the main categories these authors identify in case the links break in future, along with a few additions of my own. I recommend you read the original articles for the full details.

### Rug

[image: 4x4 array of tiles with borders at the edges.]
(16 tiles)

Draws rectangular boxes of various sizes, but can't do concave shapes. Often used for UI message boxes or cliff faces in RPG tilesets.

If you use just the top-right 3x3 section, it's commonly called a "**9-Slice**" - you lose the ability to form shapes smaller than 2x2 tiles though.

### Fence

[image: 4x4 array of tiles with connections across shared edges.]
(16 tiles)

Draws ribbons and networks of tiles connected along their shared edges.

Both Rug and Fence are examples of [Wang Tiles](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter12.html) with two edge types, they just differ in whether the corners are counted as "inside" or "outside"

### Marching Squares

[image: Tiles including all combinations of 2 foreground/background textures by 4 corners.] or [image: Alternative layout that keeps similar edges together]
(16 tiles, +2 optional alternate diagonal tiles)

You may also see this style called [Corner Tiles](http://graphics.cs.kuleuven.be/publications/LD06AWTCECC/LD06AWTCECC_paper.pdf) - they're the equivalent of Wang Tiles with matched corners instead of matched edges. [In another answer I show how this layout can be extended to three different corner textures](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/132386/39518).

### Inside/Outside

[image: 3x3 box of tiles and 4 concave inner corners, plus a background tile.]
(14 tiles)

I see this subset of Marching Squares without the diagonals fairly frequently, but I haven't found an officially accepted name for it, so I mocked up the example above using Boris's tiles. Alexandre Vaillancourt's example in the other answer is another layout of this pattern.

### The Blob

[image: 48 permutations of foreground/background edge and corner styles.]
(48 tiles)

This tileset covers an exhaustive collection of corner and edge states, where a foreground corner is always bounded by two foreground edges, but a foreground edge is allowed to slip between two background corners.

[Caeles and others at OpenGameArt have investigated various ways of packing tilesets similar to this one](https://opengameart.org/content/seamless-tileset-template-ii) - you can find several "blob" templates there.

[image: Alt blob layout as an 8x6]  [image: Alt blob layout as a 7x7]

### Sub-Blob

[image: 20 quarter-tile pieces.]
(5 tile-equivalents: 20 quarter-tile pieces that can be assembled into full tiles)

Surprisingly, you can make all 47 non-blank (all-background) tile combinations in "the Blob" with just these 20 corner pieces, assembled in different combinations.

This is used in [RPG Maker VX's autotiles](http://blog.rpgmakerweb.com/tutorials/anatomy-of-an-autotile/) and other autotiling systems to cut down on the amount of unique texturing needed to flexibly cover a wide array of shapes.

Note that the quarter-tile split puts some restrictions on how much you can bevel the corners, sometimes leading to a more blocky appearance than when using full tiles, [as illustrated by Felix Trapper here](https://forums.rpgmakerweb.com/index.php?threads/diagonal-tiles-make-a-world-of-difference-enterbrain.4249/#post-45725):

[image: Cross-fade between similar maps with and without full-tile corners.]

### Extended Autotile

[image: 9x9 grid of tile/subtile parts and two extra slots.]
(11 tile-equivalents: same 20 quarter-tiles as  Sub-Blob, plus 4 dedicated corner tiles and some redundancy)

Here I'm borrowing the name given to this by the [Rotorz tile system](http://rotorz.com/unity/tile-system/docs/466570ad-84d7-4a60-b528-378689069efa). It's also the style used by RPG Maker XP. The extra corner tiles can support a wider turning radius, or a diagonal split between foreground & background, which can help a map look more organic. Note that this particular layout includes some redundant sub-tiles (shown darkened above).

---

Here's a table summarizing what you get with each of the combinations:

```
                    9-Slice   Rug    Fence    M.S.   I/O    Blob   S.Blob  Ex.A
Tile equivalents        9     16      16      16      14     48       5     11
...with all-blank      +1     +1      +1     incl    incl   incl     +1     +1
Smallest foreground     2      1       1       2       2      1       1      1
Concave corners         N      N       Y       Y       Y      Y       Y      Y
Foreground diagonals    N      N       Y       Y       N      Y       Y      Y
Background diagonals    N      N       N       N       N      N       N      N
```